# When performing an aggregate in mongodb using mongoose an empty object is returned, why is this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first look in anger an node.js and mongodb so its possible I've done something silly or missed something obvious but given the document and the query below, why might a an empty object be returned?

### 1 Document example

```
{  
    __v: 0, 
    _id: ObjectId("50bf7f12fc71b74f3b000001"),
    amount: 452.23, 
    categoryId: 13, 
    created: ISODate("2012-12-05T17:06:26Z"), 
    description: "Test", 
    typeId: 1, 
    updated: ISODate("2012-12-05T17:06:26Z")
}
```

### 2 Problem code

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  

var Expense = new Schema({  
    description: { type: String, required: true },  
    amount: { type: Number, required: true },  
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    categoryId: { type: Number, required: true },
    typeId: { type: Number, required: true }
});

var ExpenseModel = mongoose.model('Expense', Expense);

ExpenseModel.aggregate(  
    { $group: { _id: '$typeId', total: { $sum: '$amount' }}}, 
    function (err, summary) {
        if(err){
            return res.send(500, { error: err }); 
        }

        if(summary) {
            return res.send(summary);
        } else {
            res.send(500, { error: 'couldnt find expenses' }); 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it.  Result was `[ { _id: 1, expense: 452.23 } ]`

Comment: Question updated to include the mongoose model definition.

Comment: Hmm...still works fine here when I use your schema.  Does it work when you try it in the shell?

Comment: Now that’s annoying. My collection is named Expenses, changing this it expenses and painfully everything begins to work! Convention over configuration at play here, part of the learning curve I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the name of the collection to Expenses from expenses solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your model is referencing the correct collection and that your passing `$group` before `$project`. Here's a complete example:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost:27017/myDatabase');

var expenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: { type: String, required: true },  
    amount: { type: Number, required: true },  
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    categoryId: { type: Number, required: true },
    typeId: { type: Number, required: true }
});

var Expense = db.model('expenses', expenseSchema); // make sure the first argument matches your collection's name

Expense.aggregate(  
    { $group: { _id: '$typeId', expense: { $sum: '$amount' }}}, // 'group' goes first!
    { $project: { _id: 1, expense: 1 }}, // you can only project fields from 'group'
    function(err, summary) {
        console.log(summary);
    }
);
```

This should give you an output that aggregates all expenses based on "typeId":

```
[
    { _id: 1, expense: 300.00 },
    { _id: 2, expense: 45.00 },
    ...
]
```

I just learned about aggregation to answer this question, so tell me if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Actually, in both of these cases, the `$project` isn't needed because it doesn't change anything from what the `$group` is generating itself.

Comment: In response, I've removed the $group with the same result. I've also updated the question to include more of the problematic code.

Comment: You only removed $project not $group, right? Also, what do you get? Do you get an error in `err` or is `summary` just an empty object? Try putting `console.log(arguments);` in your callback to see what's going on.

Comment: I get [] returned. Only the project was removed, group remains.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `mongoose.model('Expense', Expense);` do `db.model('Expense', Expense);` (where `db` is your mongoose connection.) `mongoose.model()` doesn't return anything, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Perhaps slightly misleading, mongoose is the result of var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Comment: I updated the code to be more complete. See if yours matches up, and pay special attention that the first argument in `db.model()` matches your collection's name. Here are the [docs for the model() method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-model).

Comment: @theabraham, figured out the issue, casing on the collection name (Expenses vs expenses). Thanks for your assitance.

Comment: Happy to hear that! If you want, there's a third argument for `db.model()` where you can explicitly name the collection you want your model to use (e.g. `db.model('modelName', myModel, 'collectionName');`)